# Did we gain an hour in december (Daylight Savings Time)

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have made a small code snippet. To tell you how old you are, to the second.

But I have found something strange. I know that time and timezones are a nightmare to work with, but this is within my own country and timezone, so I am a little confused.

If I enter the date. 27-12-2013(dd-MM-yyyy), it will show:

[image: Right time]

Which is correct. as the time here is: 08:42. The `getTimezoneOffset() is -60`

But if I go back a day it will show this:

[image: Wrong time]

It added an hour!? This is the only date it happens at, and I'm a little confused, because daylight savings time is only applied in spring and fall. The `getTimezoneOffset() is ALSO -60`

**Hope you can shed some light on this.**

**Timezone**: http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?s=standard&tz=Europe/Copenhagen
**Javascript**: GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
**Country**: Denmark
**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/d6kBJ/4/

```
var $output = $(".js-ageoutput");
var bd = new Date(2000, 0, 01);
bd.setHours(0);
bd.setMinutes(0);
bd.setSeconds(0);

function showTotalAge() {
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - bd.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    displayAge(ageDate)
    loopAge();
}

function displayAge(age) {
    var yearOld = Math.abs(age.getFullYear() - 1970);
    var months = age.getMonth();
    var days = age.getDate() - 1;
    var h = age.getHours() - 1;
    var m = age.getMinutes();
    var s = age.getSeconds();
    $output.html(yearOld + ' years <br/>' + months + ' months <br/>' + days + ' days <br/>' + h + 'hours <br/>' + m + ' minutes <br/>' + s + ' seconds<br/>');
}

function loopAge() {
    setTimeout(showTotalAge, 1000);
}
loopAge();

$(".js-birthday").change(function () {
    var vArr = $(this).val().split('-');
    bd = new Date(vArr[0], parseInt(vArr[1], 10) - 1, vArr[2]);
    bd.setHours(0);
    bd.setMinutes(0);
    bd.setSeconds(0);
    console.log(bd);
});
```

Comment: There's nothing much to understand. Just create a `Date` object and check what `getTimezoneOffset` returns. Although it seems odd to me, it should happen in October - for European countries, at least.

Comment: @MaxArt, how do you figure? Theres plenty to understand. It is very odd, also your "suggestion", makes it weirder, the offset is the exact same. Both dates offset is `-60`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a deeper inspection of your code, here's your mistake:

```
var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
```

The point is: *never* create a `Date` object out of a difference of dates, because it would make no sense. What you get is a `Date` object that represents the instant `ageDifMs` milliseconds after January 1st, 1970 UTC, and that's what methods like `getMonth`, `getDate`, `getHours` and so on refer to.

So, you got a date like March 28th, 1970 and that's when the Daylight Saving Time happens.

If you want to know the difference of two dates in terms of months and days and so on, you either can compute the differences of the results of `getMonth` and the other methods, or fix the length of a year, a month and compute the single values using modulus and divisions.

Also, you would rather use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` for timed continuous tasks.

Comment: Very nice catch! You are completely right, and I can't believe I hadn't thought about that... The last part, I do know though. Thanks for you time :)